# how can i import an iframe html code from a string

Tags: javascript, python, html

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" allow="fullscreen; autoplay; encrypted-media" src="https://games.construct.net/174/latest" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" msallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" allowpaymentrequest="false" referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock allow-orientation-lock allow-popups" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I have this source code as a **string**.
how can i change it into an HTML code to run?
I tried appendChiled command but i don't know how i should use it.

I just got errors or empty iframes that show this string code on it.

Comment: what? I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

I made a snippet for your below. I'm not completely sure what you're looking for based on your question but let me know if this works for you.

```js
//Set string as a variable
var string = '<iframe width="560" height="315" allow="fullscreen; autoplay; encrypted-media" src="https://games.construct.net/174/latest" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" msallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" allowpaymentrequest="false" referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock allow-orientation-lock allow-popups" scrolling="no"></iframe>'

//Get container div by its id
var container = document.getElementById("container")

//Check if container has content, if there's nothing in the container then show the string
if (container.innerHTML.length < 1) {
container.innerHTML = string;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the string inside html() function using jquery

Example :

var x = "

### hello world

"

$("#div_id").html(x);

in your case

var string = 'your iframe code as string'

$("#container").html(string);

## ***Hope it helps***